# Correct build of my sql table regarding telephone calls

Tags: mysql

I have a database (well more like I wanna build it) where i will save telephone calls data. Let me start by saying that i will be importinh 10.000 calls per week so imagine some millions records. 
So far I have these fields.

```
id -> int unsigned auto_increment
date_and_time -> int unsigned
duration -> smallInt unsigned
type -> tinyInt unsigned
calling_id -> int unsigned
called_id -> int unsinged
```

The calling and called ids refer to the telephone numbers table.
What i need help with is this. I have a class in php that check if a call already exists and if NOT then inserts it. So i need the fastest way to query for an existant call.

I have index of date_and_time, calling_id AND called_id together, as well as calling_id, called_id AND date_and_time together.

At the moment i just use

```
SELECT * FROM communications WHERE calling_id = :cngID AND called_id = :cdId AND date_and_time = :dnt
```

Is there a way to maybe search for the date first and if found THEN check if the calling and called ids are matching. I know i can use 2 queries for that but i m just wondering which would be the fastest way. I m new with my sql so i m wondering if there is a complex query that works faster than my simple SELECT query or if 2 queries could maybe work faster as well.

Any insights
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is up to you to specify *what* you want to query, and up to your database system to figure out *how* to obtain your data. So you specify the conditions and the RDBS optimizes the query to execute it as fast as possible. Which might well mean that it will search by date and time first if there exists a suitable index for it. The `EXPLAIN` command can be used to see the execution plan, where mysql actually tells you what it's doing, and in which order.

That said, there are ways to force tests into a given order. You could abuse the `HAVING` clause, or you could nest queries, or something like this. But I'd advise against this, particularly if you are a beginner.